# Render problem. Mesh is cut on final render or in render display

Tags: rendering

I used mirror mod., have 2 objects. The problem is that in final render (F12) it is cutted in some strange way. Part of the mesh is vanished, but it exists on my 'solid' view. It makes me mad. Please, help me. THx.
[image]

Comment: (cycles render)

Comment: Please, add a screenshot this modifiers and 3d view.

Comment: It's still not clear. Can you provide a blend-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, im not very smart. I didnt know, that 'render' ratio, that gave opportunity to see object in render is switced off

Comment: Now you posted the screenshot I see my answer is not relevant, so I removed it. I'm not sure about what you meant with "render" ratio. I do suspect, though, that your problem is the Subsurf modifier. You can confirm it by either lowering the "Render" subdivisions to the same value you're using in the "View" and seeing if the issue goes away when rendering, or increasing the "View" to the "Render" value and see if the issue appears in the Viewport.